# Series of (tiny) Questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, users, asking-questions

Well, don't get me wrong, but am I the only who finds this kind of "question behavior" questionable?
10+ Questions on the same piece of code.

Take a look at the question history of this [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404020/awakefromnib#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_recent-asort_votes).

Answer (score 9):

Each question should be evaluated individually without taking into account other questions the user may have asked.

If a question, by itself, is useful, there shouldn't be an issue. If it's a lousy question or can't stand by itself, it should be down-voted or closed.

If enough of a user's questions are down-voted or closed, they'll be barred from asking any more and the problem solves itself.

Comment: This would be exactly why I *haven't* made of habit of trying to nix this pattern. Nicely stated. But I can't bring my self to spend any time policing the individual questions either...

Comment: @dmckee - What do you mean "time policing"? Clicking on down vote takes a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Peter: It takes time to read and determine if a question falls inside or outside the bounds. If you're banging away like a machine gun you're doing it wrong. And when you encounter a poster who has splashed a dozen questions onto the site in a few hours it can take quite a while to work out which are "legitimate" and which are not. Thus, while I approve of Mark's comment in general, I'm open to a limit to the acceptable number of minutely varied questions on a single topic. We're *not* here to do the asker's work for them in every detail.

Comment: @dmckee - I only read the questions that interest me, and I only vote on those. If everyone does this then bad questions simply fall off the front page due to either lack of views / votes / responses or downvotes if the question seemed interesting but was bad.

Answer (score 5):

Without examining this case I'll note that these users sometimes exhibit an unwillingness to learn anything or do any work for themselves.

I simple loath that approach, and ignore their questions out of self defense.

But I could get behind a movement to define some limits beyond which micro-questioning is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404020/awakefromnib) in question has asked 14 (**FOURTEEN**) questions pertaining to the same problem:

- [Generating permutations of NSArray elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791265/generating-permutations-of-nsarray-elements)
- [How to pass a string to a function in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791730/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-function-in-objective-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791843/how-to-convert-this-c-code-to-objective-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791927/can-you-tell-me-what-this-code-does-in-pseudocode-closed
- [How to convert this code to use string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792736/how-to-convert-this-code-to-use-string)
- [What kind of algorithm do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792462/what-kind-of-algorithm-do-i-need)
- [How to make function return string in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792923/how-to-make-function-return-string-in-c)
- [How to make this function recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793116/how-to-make-this-function-recursive)
- [iostream and sstream for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794931/iostream-and-sstream-for-objective-c)
- [How to change this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794949/how-to-change-this-code)
- [How to use printf with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796106/how-to-use-printf-with-nsstring)
- [What does this line of code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796260/what-does-this-line-of-code-do)
- [How to get a single character from an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796292/how-to-get-a-single-character-from-an-nsstring)
- [Why doesn't this code produce the correct output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796312/why-doesnt-this-code-produce-the-correct-output)

Some of these are "convert my code from [language] to objective-c," some others are extremely basic questions (eg: how to print a NSString).

Comment: @Peter IMO many of the questions could be merged with little loss of content.

Comment: Yes, but that goes for thousands of questions on Stack Overflow. The ability to merge a question into another is not really an indication of the question's quality. ---- In fact most people argue that the more precise and narrow a question is, the better it is.

Comment: Yes, the user in question breaks the question into smaller pieces in order to narrow it down and make it more precise in an attempt to get better answers.

Answer (score -9):

**Disclosure: "the user" referenced below is actually the author of this very post.**

---

Sometimes the answers given aren't very good so the questioner has to probe further.

I noticed that the user is using the "Socratic Method." It is a form of question and answer dialog used in law schools and is one of the best ways to learn anything. The user in question is probably not just interested in a quick solution but a good answer that he can learn something from. If the answers he get doesn't nail his question then he tries another path until he finds a good answer. The questions, while related, are not simply repetitions or rephrasings of each other, they are legitimate questions in their own right.

So I don't think the user is doing anything wrong. He's doing thing differently, and his way is probably better. He's probably a good student that's not afraid to look dumb so he asks a lot of questions in class and gets lots of As.

Comment: I've only peeked into two questions, but to me at least some of [the](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3796292/84237) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796312/why-doesnt-this-code-produce-the-correct-output/3796369#3796369) don't indicate "The user in question is probably not just interested in a quick solution but a good answer that he can learn something from"...

Comment: And as an aside: students who ask a lot of questions in class, and hence take a lot of time from the professor and other students, can be quite annoying. Others get A's from reading the book, listening to answers or trying themselves.

Comment: Ow wow, Anthony Fontanilla aka awakeFromNib, you're talking [about yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151716?tab=accounts#tab-top) in the 3rd person. That is not why I alerted you about this very discussion. Not good. -100 if I could.

Comment: **sockpuppets,** wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!

Comment: Professors actually like it when students ask questions. If questions weren't important then people could just learn by reading books, looking at powerpoints, and watching videos, and lectures wouldn't be important. No one would have to come to class. However, lectures are important, particularly because it gives students and professors time to have question and answer discussions. The students that are annoyed by the questions are usually not the A students.

Comment: @Anthony, have you been a professor? Yes, in general it's nice if your audience asks questions. But if the questions are like "it doesn't work", after which the lecturer is using time to try to figure out what exactly one is asking, and time to answer, then you might still get that A but others get less time from the professor. And even worse: the professor might decide to not work late and just ignore new questions outside of the hours the work contract dictates. (Hint: the contract hours here are zero. Asking question is not a holy grail.)

Comment: @Anthony: At times I have been a professor. I can assure you that there is a difference between a few insightful questions that show that the student is thinking and a barrage of minutely varying trivia: the later show that the student is *not* thinking.

Comment: In the Socratic Method, the teacher asks the questions to lead the student to a conclusion. It is difficult to imagine how anyone could consider this sequence of questions to fall under the Socratic Method.

Comment: There is no professor here that is asking questions to lead the student to a conclusion. Therefore I take the initiative to ask those questions. I eventually reach the conclusion through a series of questions and answers. It's practically the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew This is not a sock puppet. You can see his associated accounts on his profile.

Comment: @NullUserException -- you'd know that *if* you viewed his profile. But repeatedly referring to himself in the third person can only serve to imply that AnFon is an unconnected individual defending the user in question. It should have been I-I-I all along. Quote: **The user in question is probably not just interested...** Are you kidding me? That's being a sock puppet! An acknowledged sock puppet is still a sock puppet.

Comment: Sock pocket shmocket. It's not important.

Comment: No, @Anthony, **IT IS IMPORTANT**. These communities are here to help. And when people are *wondering* if your way of asking questions is harmful to the community, you're abusing the voice of that very same community by faking someone to support your behaviour. You don't have to agree with us, but please, don't ignore feedback.

Comment: I wasn't trying to fake support. Anyway you shouldn't judge an argument by how many people support it.

Comment: Ok, then please tell us why you posted this in its current form?

Comment: Because people will in fact do that.

Comment: Now you're using the 3rd person to talk about yourself again. ;-)